# Issue in open excel from C# code

Tags: c#, excel

Am trying to read an excel in C# web application, The functionality is working fine when application is accessed with in the windows server hosted or when solution is tested in development machine.
But am getting below error when I access the application hosted on a server from a different system.

Please suggest, what could be the issue.

```
filePath = FileUpload.PostedFile.FileName;  
xlApp = new Excel.Application(); 
xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@filePath);
```

> 'C:\Users\xys\Desktop\xyz.xls' could not be found. Check the spelling
>   of the file name, and verify that the file location is correct. If you
>   are trying to open the file from your list of most recently used
>   files, make sure that the file has not been renamed, moved, or
>   deleted.

Comment: and does the file at that location exist? Does whatever is running this application have permissions to access that file? The error message seems pretty obvious to me

Comment: yes file is present in the location , when same is tested from local development solution or from with in the server hosted it is working. But getting error when application hosted on to server is accessed from different system(ex:development system)

Comment: **and** Does whatever is running this application have permissions to access that file?

Comment: maybe you don't have permissions to that folder \ file ?

Comment: Using `Microsoft.Office.Interop` to automate Office on a Server is not supported by Microsoft, and is not recommended as it is very prone to errors. You should probably consider switching to some library dedicated to reading/writing of excel files, without needing the full Microsoft Excel installed on the PC (i.e. libraries like OpenXML, EPPlus, etc). Maybe have a look at the following support article from Microsoft: [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office)

Comment: does the server in which you are getting error has excel installed in it ? Excel.Application com object is added to the system when Excel is installed (Exception will be like class not registered), you can consider the options given by @bassfader

Comment: Hi All, Thanks for the replies, yes It's access issue server account running the application do not have access to the client system path. I have used a shared path(which server account has access) to place the input files and browsing the same, now its working fine.

Comment: Yes, Server is having the required excel component installed, I will explore on the other implementation suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might get this error if you are trying to browse a file from your local computer and try to read the file contents in code behind using the path.

To fix the issue, either read contents in the client side and pass the data to server side or place the file in a shared drive which is accessible from both client machine and server machine and then browse the file.

Comment: Thanks, am using a shared path(which server account has access) to place the input files and browsing the same, now its working fine.